# What is the set of homotopy classes of maps of $X$ into $Y$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Munkres's Topology denotes the set of homotopy classes of maps of $X$ into $Y$ by $[X,Y]$. How do we write $[X,Y]$ in the sense of set, i.e., $[X,Y]=\{[f] \in ... | ... \}$? Is an element of $[X,Y]$ a class of continuous maps from $X$ to $Y$?

Comment: It's a collection of equivalence classes of maps.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you. I understand that $f$~$g$ iff there exists a homotopy between them. But I want to know do these functions need to be continuous? I am doing an exercise, some solutions use the straight line homotopy to argue that $H(t,x) = (1-t)f(x) +tg(x)$ is continuous, where $f$ and $g$ are in different homotopy classes. But I am not sure whether $f$ and $g$ are assumed to be continuous with this definition. If they are not, then I think we can't say $H$ is continuous. Would you mind writing $[X,Y]$ as a set?

Comment: Yes: $[X,Y]=\{[f]\,\,|\,\,f:X\to Y,f\text{ is continuous}\}$

Comment: @user546106 It is extremely unlikely that you are dealing with non-continuous homotopies. There is such theory but 99% of time everything is assumed to be at least continuous.

Comment: @freakish By definition of homotopy on my textbook, a homotopy is defined to be a continuous map between two functions $f$ and $g$. But it doesn't clarify whether $f$ and $g$ are continuous. Can $f$ and $g$ be discontinuous?

Comment: @user546106 If $H$ is continuous then so is $f$ and $g$. The relationship $H(x,0)=f(x)$ and $H(x,1)=g(x)$ implies that since both $f$ and $g$ can be expressed as a composition of $H$ and continuous embedding $X\to X\times I$.

Comment: @freakish Thank you very much. I understand the definition better now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start with the set of all continuous functions:

$$C(X,Y)=\{f:X\to Y\ |\ f\text{ is continuous}\}$$

then you define a relation:

$$f\sim g\text{ if and only if }f\text{ is homotopic to }g$$

and finally you define the quotient set

$$[X,Y]=C(X,Y)/\sim$$

Elements of $[X,Y]$ are **sets** which are equivalence classes

$$[f]_{\sim}=\{g\in C(X,Y)\ |\ g\sim f\}$$
$$[X,Y]=\{[f]_{\sim}\ |\ f\in C(X,Y)\}$$

For example if $Y=\mathbb{R}$ (or any other contractible space) then $[X,Y]$ has only one point.

Another example is $[S^1, S^1]$ which is equinumerous to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you. That's very clear. I appreciate it! I added this on my textbook.